# How to change PopupMenuItem width in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

My code is like this
[image]

I want make Item width to match parent
but I can't change PopupMenuItem width.

I tried text wrap Continer and set width exactly but it not working.

How can I do?

Comment: Show us a little more code, like the parent you are trying to match

Comment: Did you find the answer ? If yes, please share it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

container with inside the popupmenuitem

```
        new PopupMenuButton<Choice>(
            onSelected: _select,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return choices.map((Choice choice) {
                return PopupMenuItem<Choice>(
                  value: choice,
                  child: new Container(
                    width: 100.0,
                    child: Text(choice.title)
                  ),
                );
              }).toList();
            },
          ),
```

other code for the complete example

```
  void _select(Choice choice) {
      print(choice);
  }

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'Car', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  const Choice(title: 'Bicycle', icon: Icons.directions_bike),
  const Choice(title: 'Boat', icon: Icons.directions_boat),
  const Choice(title: 'Bus', icon: Icons.directions_bus),
  const Choice(title: 'Train', icon: Icons.directions_railway),
  const Choice(title: 'Walk', icon: Icons.directions_walk),
];
```

Comment: How to set full width to PopupMenuItem? I tried to give full width using MediaQuery.of(context).size.width but it doesn't work.

Comment: This method does not work for me. I ended up using Expanded

Comment: Expanded doesn't work for me either...

Comment: Expanded did not work for me either, How did you do yours?

Answer (score 3):

change the value of  maxWidth  in the constraints

sample code

```
 Widget _offsetPopup() => PopupMenuButton<int>(
constraints: BoxConstraints(
    minWidth: 2.0 * 56.0,
    maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  ),
  itemBuilder: (context) => [
        PopupMenuItem(
          value: 1,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Expanded(
              child: Text(
                "To Receive",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
 

  offset: Offset(0, 40));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
PopupMenuButton(
   offset: Offset(0, 52.sp),
   constraints: BoxConstraints(
     minWidth: 0.5.sw,
     maxWidth: 0.5.sw,
   ),
 
   child: Text("Open PopupMenu"),
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => [
     PopupMenuItem(
         // padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.sp),
         child: Container(width:500 , height: 200,child:Text("Item 1")))
   ],
 )
```